CSS: suppress hover effect for dissociate <label> and <input>
In below example, CSS "helpfully" triggers input:hover when the label is hovered. How can this label hover effect be suppressed with only changing the CSS, so that the input border only changes when it is hovered itself? pointer-events: none is not an option.


input:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
<div><label for="foo">label</label></div>
<div><input id="foo"/></div>




@BrettDonald Right you are - interesting. (I think I got this on my mind because Chrome's DevTools raises an Issues flag)

Just remove for="foo". The HTML spec does not say that a label element must be linked to a control. In any case, what matters is what browsers actually do, and browsers will cope just fine without the for attribute.

When an element is hovered, then so are its ancestor elements. But this doesn't apply to the :hover matched by the labelled control. So we can test the parent element of the input to see if it's also hovered. Like this:


input:is(:hover > :hover) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
<div><label for="foo">label</label></div>
<div><input id="foo"/></div>



Alternatively, you could use :hover > input:hover which amounts to the same thing.
Note that this requires that the input control's parent element is not an ancestor of the label element. While this is true for the example is given, it is possible to construct situations where the dissociated elements do not meet this requirement.

A bit hacky but it works.


div:has(label:hover) + div input {
  border: revert;
}

input:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
<div><label for="foo">label</label></div>
<div><input id="foo"/></div>



